# Grant an IAP without user-interaction

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

How can I grant an in-app purchase to a user without having the user need to go through the steps of "buying" it from the store. The IAP is free.

I want to do this from within the app, and without needing a web service. Something like `CurrentApp.GiveThisUserTheProduct(string productId)` .

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. what's the use case? if the IAP is free, why not include the feature in the app directly? P.S. wasn't me

Comment: @AlexDrenea It's free now. But might become non-free. I don't want to make a current user pay for something he had for free until then.

Comment: got it. still, don't think it's supported. You need to go though all the IAP steps to complete a purchase even if it's free.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the "purchase" as a local value in the local settings collection or in a "license file" on disk.

When the user accesses the feature you'll check against that stored value whether or not that user is allowed access.

Later if the user tries to buy the feature you can check whether the user already have it by checking the local value and show a message explaining it's already enabled.